# React Native and Parse.FacebookUtils

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to sign users into my React-Native app using Parse and Facebook but it seems like the Facebook JS SDK is dependent on the dom. How can I sign in a user with facebook?

I'm currently using https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login to log the user in natively, so I have access to their auth token, ect. But can't use the Parse.FacebookUtils.login() without the FB JS SDK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your authData from the native FB SDK, you can bypass the FacebookUtils.init() call entirely. This should log in to a Parse user with FB:

```
Parse.User._logInWith('facebook', {
  authData: {
    id: FB_USER_ID,
    access_token: USER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    expiration_date: TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DATE
  }
});
```

This'll return a Promise, same as Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn()

Comment: It appears this code path still requires FB JS SDK to exist

Comment: This is without calling `Parse.FacebookUtils.init()`? All references to `FB` are avoided if the authentication provider is never registered with the Parse SDK

Comment: Maybe edit the answer then, so people don't have to read through the comments?

Comment: @Andrewl how do you signup with the token ? how do you verify if the user existed or not?

Comment: @AndrewI How do I send other user data with this call?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around this by commenting out the references to FB in the Parse SDK Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn flow and removing the safety checks. The FB SDK isn't actually needed to authenticate a user with Parse if you already have the authData object.

Obviously not an ideal solution, so leaving this open

Answer (score 0):

In React Native, you can sign in an user with Facebook by making use of the  RCTBridgeModule/NativeModules API.

In essence, you would have to write a native module that can directly access the native Facebook Login Manager API.

You can find more information about this process [here](http://brentvatne.ca/facebook-login-with-react-native/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm logging the user in natively fine, I'd then like to use the auth token to log the user into parse

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn` actually does not rely upon the FB JS SDK, so you can call it directly (as long as you pass in the `authData` object).

In case it's helpful to anyone else, I ran into difficulties linking and unlinking Parse accounts with Facebook accounts.  The `unlink` method, for instance, relies on the FB JS SDK.  I worked around this by 1. not calling `Parse.FacebookUtils.init`, 2. creating a "fake Facebook provider":

```
var FakeFacebookProvider = {
  getAuthType: function () {
    return 'facebook';
  },
  restoreAuthentication: function () {
    return true;
  },
};
```

and 3. passing this in to `Parse.User._isLinked` and `Parse.User._unlinkFrom`:

```
if (user._isLinked(FakeFacebookProvider)) {
  user._unlinkFrom(FakeFacebookProvider, {
```

So far this is working well.  This would probably achieve the same thing as Tarrence's answer, without needing to edit the Parse code.

We really need a React Native compatible version of `Parse.FacebookUtils` that doesn't rely on the FB JS SDK!